# Using tikzpictures as symbols in glossaries

Tags: tikz-pgf, glossaries

In a text, I'm using a `tikzpicture` as a math symbol. 
I'd like to reference this symbol in a glossary. It seems to me that makeindex doesn't know how to draw the picture. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[toc, section, numberline]{glossaries}

\newcommand{\Plus}{\mathord{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0ex, line width=1, scale=0.13]
\draw (1,0) -- (1,2);
\draw (0,1) -- (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{gls:Plus}{name={\ensuremath{\Plus}},description=\nopostdesc} % Does not work; change \Plus to, e.g., + else to compile.

\begin{document}
$A \gls{gls:Plus} B$

$A \Plus B$
\printglossary[type=main, style=list, nonumberlist=false]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Here's the log I get when I try to compile, regardless of `\protect`, or not: http://pastebin.com/iJjw9GVQ

Answer (score 7):

Fragile command. Moving argument. So:

```
name={\ensuremath{\protect\Plus}}
```

Comment: While this might be an additional issue, changing the code in the minimal example does not make it compilable.

Comment: Yes, it does (I checked at the time and again just now) You probably have corrupt .aux file from a previous attempt, delete that and do a clean run

Comment: Hm. Interestingly enough, deleting .aux files, and even saving the code as a different file did not change the described behaviour for me. (The newly compiled file did not even create an aux-file.) Can an outdated version of `glossaries`, or any other package be the cause? I've updated the interesting part of the log to the initial question, which might help to see what the cause of my problems is.